# difference between trial and observation

Tags: terminology

What's the difference between a trial and an observation?  My sense is that an observation is a measurement of a variable for a single trial.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put,
A Trial —— is the act of carrying out an experiment, while
An Observation —— is the value of a data point used in an experiment

Note: The total number of data points used in an experiment, is also known as `sample size` or `number of observations`, `n`